# Pandas select discontinuous dataframe date slices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF with datetime index:
this select works fine

```
threeyrs=actdf['01/01/2010':'12/31/2012']
```

but I'd like to get something like this (to exclude 2010):

```
threeyrs=actdf['01/01/2009':'12/01/2009','01/01/2011':'12/01/2012']
```

which gives me "unhashable type"
and this gives me a string

```
threeyrs=actdf['01/01/2009':'12/31/2009'],actdf['01/01/2011':'12/31/2012']
```

Is there a convenient way?
dataFrame looks like

```
            Units
date    
2000-05-01   3041
2000-06-01   3079
2000-07-01   2455
2000-08-01   2671
2000-09-01   2220
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
threeyrs = pd.concat([actdf['01/01/2009':'12/01/2009'], actdf['01/01/2011':'12/01/2012']])
```

Comment: @dartdog Ah, missed a set of brackets. You're the compiler I never had!

Comment: I like it better than the other answer! Seems nicer syntax... Let me give it a go..

Comment: Works great and nice syntax with the date format and easily extensible

Answer (score 4):

0.12 & 0.13

```
In [57]: df[((df.index>Timestamp('20000801')) & (df.index<=Timestamp('20000901'))) | ((df.index>Timestamp('20000501')) & (df.index<=Timestamp('20000601')))]
Out[57]: 
            units
date             
2000-06-01   3079
2000-09-01   2220

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

0.13 only

```
In [58]: df.query('(date>20000801 & date<=20000901) | (date>20000501 & date<=20000601)')
Out[58]: 
            units
date             
2000-06-01   3079
2000-09-01   2220

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: # 2 did it for me (i'm on dev)